Typescript module augmentation with third party library
I have a typescript server project using a third party plugin called ah-sequelize-plugin. It requires that I create config files that augment/add to their config files.
Here is an example of one of their config files websocket.d.ts:
import { ActionheroConfigInterface } from "actionhero";
declare const namespace = "websocket";
declare module "actionhero" {
    interface ActionheroConfigInterface {
        [namespace]: ReturnType<typeof DEFAULT[typeof namespace]>;
    }
}
export declare const DEFAULT: {
    websocket: (config: ActionheroConfigInterface) => {
        enabled: boolean;
        clientUrl: string;
        clientJsPath: string;
        clientJsName: string;
        destroyClientsOnShutdown: boolean;
        server: {};
        client: {
            apiPath: string;
            cookieKey: string;
        };
    };
};
export {};

Here is a portion of my attempted implementation:
import { ActionheroConfigInterface } from "actionhero";

const namespace = "websocket";

declare module "actionhero" {
  export interface ActionheroConfigInterface {
    [namespace]: ReturnType<(typeof DEFAULT)[typeof namespace]>;
  }
}

export const DEFAULT = {
  [namespace]: (config: ActionheroConfigInterface) => {
    return {
      enabled: true,
      // you can pass a FQDN (like https://company.com) here or 'window.location.origin'
      clientUrl: "window.location.origin",
      // Directory to render client-side JS.
      // Path should start with "/" and will be built starting from api.config..general.paths.public
      clientJsPath: "javascript/",
      // the name of the client-side JS file to render.  Both `.js` and `.min.js` versions will be created
      // do not include the file extension
      // set to `undefined` to not render the client-side JS on boot
      clientJsName: "ActionheroWebsocketClient",
      // should the server signal clients to not reconnect when the server is shutdown/reboot
      destroyClientsOnShutdown: false,

      // websocket Server Options:
  // websocket Server Options:
  server: {
    authorization: null,
    pathname: "/ws",
    parser: "JSON",
    transformer: "websockets",
    plugin: {},
    pingInterval: 30000,
    origins: "*",
    methods: ["GET", "HEAD", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"],
    credentials: true,
    maxAge: "30 days",
    exposed: false,
  },

  // websocket Client Options:
  client: {
    apiPath: "/api", // the api base endpoint on your actionhero server
    // the cookie name we should use for shared authentication between WS and web connections
    cookieKey: config.web.fingerprintOptions.cookieKey,
    timeout: 10000,
    pingTimeout: 45000,
    strategy: ["online", "timeout", "disconnect"],
    manual: false,
    websockets: true,
    network: true,
    transport: {},
    queueSize: Infinity,
  },

The problem I'm having is a type mismatch between the third party config files and my implementations of them.
Specifically, here's the error I'm receiving:
Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property '[namespace]' must be of type '{ enabled: boolean; clientUrl: string; clientJsPath: string; clientJsName: string; destroyClientsOnShutdown: boolean; server: { authorization: any; pathname: string; parser: string; transformer: string; ... 6 more ...; exposed: boolean; }; client: { ...; }; }', but here has type '{ enabled: boolean; clientUrl: string; clientJsPath: string; clientJsName: string; destroyClientsOnShutdown: boolean; server: {}; client: { apiPath: string; cookieKey: string; }; }'
I'm fairly new to Typescript, so I'm unfamiliar with how to even begin addressing this. My understanding so far is that there are specific properties I'm "extending", such as the server property that contains sub-properties that are not defined in the third-party file. I thought, though, that redeclaring the declare module "actionhero" code followed by the interface would allow me to "extend" these properties, but this clearly isn't working.
Here's a link to the plugin I'm using: https://github.com/actionhero/ah-sequelize-plugin
Edit: Additional context...  Here is my plugins.ts
import { PluginConfig } from "actionhero";
import * as path from "path";

const namespace = "plugins";

declare module "actionhero" {
  export interface ActionheroConfigInterface {
    [namespace]: ReturnType<(typeof DEFAULT)[typeof namespace]>;
  }
}

export const DEFAULT: { [namespace]: () => PluginConfig } = {
  [namespace]: () => {
    /*
    If you want to use plugins in your application, include them here:

    return {
      'myPlugin': { path: __dirname + '/../node_modules/myPlugin' }
    }

    You can also toggle on or off sections of a plugin to include (default true for all sections):

    return {
      'myPlugin': {
        path: __dirname + '/../node_modules/myPlugin',
        actions: true,
        tasks: true,
        initializers: true,
        servers: true,
        public: true,
        cli: true
      }
    }
    */
    const sequelizePlugin =
      process.env.NODE_ENV === "build"
        ? {}
        : {
            "ah-sequelize-plugin": {
              path: path.join(
                process.cwd(),
                "node_modules",
                "ah-sequelize-plugin"
              ),
            },
          };
    return sequelizePlugin;
  },
};

Specifically, the error started when I added this to my tsconfig.json file,
"include": ["./src/**/*", "node_modules/ah-sequelize-plugin/**/*.d.ts"]
I needed to add the ah-sequelize-plugin because for some reason the api.sequelize object that I use throughout the project was not being typed. It had no autocompletion and everything was typed as any. After adding this to the include in the json file, the sequelize object is typed, but it now gives me these mismatched typed errors from the config files

Deleted my comment because it wasn't relevant, but it would be easier if you can share your project dir tree, plugin.ts and at what point you get this error.

@avifen I've added additional context

usually you don't include typescript files or .d.ts files from node_modules specifically in your tsconfig.json. The above namespace extension looks a bit clunky and over complicated. firstly I'd suggest not using 'declare' in your above statement. I'd intead look up the generic for PluginConfig. Usually you can put in something like this for thirdparty libraries: PluginConfig<{MyPlugin: {} etc...>

I've also noticed that library is 5 years old. Consider this library: https://dev.to/jctaveras/sequelize-typescript-what-you-need-to-know-41mj

@SteveTomlin Unfortunately, I don't think changing this plugin is an option at the moment. Also, this plugin bridges actionhero and sequelize, I am already using a library for sequelize-typescript

@SteveTomlin One thing I notice in the ah-sequelize-plugin library is that its package.json file does not have a types property. Could this possibly be the reason that the api.sequelize object is not typed (even though there is a .d.ts file explicitly typing this object in the library)?

@Zayum yeah just check you follow all the installs for the @types files here from the npm: https://github.com/actionhero/ah-sequelize-plugin in your devDependencies
